# Как разместить ссылки горизонтально

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте. Хочу разместить несколько ссылок, и чтобы у них появлялся горизонтальный скролл (если ссылки не влазят все на экран горизонтально).

Но получается у меня немного иначе...

```css
.specz-tb {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 55px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="specz-tb">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">Oбзор Производителя</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Автокосметика и автохимия</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Автошины / Диски</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Аккумуляторы</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Аксессуары</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Двигатель</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Информация о подделках</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Крепеж</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Кузовные детали</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Масла и жидкости</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">ОБЗОР</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Подвеска</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Подшипники</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Прокладки, сальники</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Ремни</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Ролики</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Рулевое управление</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Система выпуска отработавших газов</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Система отопления и вентиляции</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Система охлаждения двигателя</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Система очистки стекол и фар</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Стекла</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Топливная система</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Тормозная система</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Трансмиссия</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Фильтры</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Шланги</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Электрооборудование</a>
</div>
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам надо ваш блок поместить в обёртку, этой обёртке задать overflow, а самому блоку - white-space: nowrap (чтобы не было переноса строки):

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: auto;
}

.specz-tb {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 55px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="specz-tb">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">Oбзор Производителя</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Автокосметика и автохимия</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Автошины / Диски</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Аккумуляторы</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Аксессуары</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Двигатель</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Информация о подделках</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Крепеж</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Кузовные детали</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Масла и жидкости</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">ОБЗОР</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Подвеска</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Подшипники</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Прокладки, сальники</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Ремни</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Ролики</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Рулевое управление</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Система выпуска отработавших газов</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Система отопления и вентиляции</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Система охлаждения двигателя</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Система очистки стекол и фар</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Стекла</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Топливная система</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Тормозная система</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Трансмиссия</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Фильтры</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Шланги</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Электрооборудование</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: а что бы ширина как-то автоматически подстраивалась? так как ссылок может быть неопределенное количество...

Comment: Тогда не понятно что вы хотите, конкретизируйте вопрос

Comment: @kizoso разместить ссылки горизонтально, с полосой прокрутки.

Comment: @Денис, тогда ещё проще: width вообще убираете и добавляете white-space: nowrap (не будет переноса строки). Я переделал ответ

Comment: @humster_spb то что нужно! спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.specz-tb {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 55px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="specz-tb">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">Oбзор Производителя</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">Автокосметика и автохимия</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">Автошины / Диски</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">Аккумуляторы</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">Аксессуары</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">Двигатель</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">Информация о подделках</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">Крепеж</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">Кузовные детали</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">Масла и жидкости</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">ОБЗОР</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">Подвеска</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">Подшипники</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">Прокладки, сальники</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">Ремни</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">Ролики</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">Рулевое управление</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">Система выпуска отработавших газов</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">Система отопления и вентиляции</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">Система охлаждения двигателя</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">Система очистки стекол и фар</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">Стекла</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">Топливная система</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">Тормозная система</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">Трансмиссия</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">Фильтры</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">Шланги</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">Электрооборудование</a>
</div>
```